# VBA - MouseDown and MouseUp to trigger Macro

Tags: excel, vba

I've seen a few codes that work just fine to capture MouseDown and MouseUp events within TextBoxes, Shapes, CommandButtons, etc., such as the one below:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_MouseDown(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
'Do Stuff
End Sub
```

Is there any way to capture MouseDown and MouseUp events on a Worksheet in order to trigger a macro?

Comment: It looks to me like you answered your own question. The answer is yes, use the MouseDown event.

Comment: The issue is that I can't seem to make a macro run when I press MouseDown or MouseUp. That's what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: I dont understand why not, you just type the name of the function/sub in the event. What is confusing about that?

Comment: Sorry, it wasn't clear on my question that I want to do it on a Worksheet, not on a UserForm.

Comment: Ah. Worksheets do not have a MouseDown event. You could try using the `Worksheet_SelectionChange` event, depending on what you are trying to do, but that's probably as close as you are going to get.

Comment: here is one answer : https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/28343702/Trap-left-mouse-click-in-Excel-when-clicking-on-a-cell.html

Comment: `Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick` may be a better event - less likely to happen by accident.  Failing that Jaarfar Tribak has some code which imitates a cell click event in the link.  I haven't posted code as an answer as I don't understand it. :):  https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/459110-vb-macro-capture-mouseclick-excel-sheet-cell.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about in the general userform, then you can use a format like this:

```
Private Sub UserForm_MouseDown(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
'Do things here
End Sub
```

I don't believe it works with a worksheet though.

Comment: That's the issue. I edited my question because it didn't mention I want to do this on a Worksheet level, not on an UserForm.